# Sink argument implementation of assignment operator and language defect

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator

In his key note lecture at the C++now Conference 2012, Sean Parent introduced the notion of “sink arguments”. His recommendation is to pass arguments by value if they are “consumed” by a function. The sink argument is then moved or copied, dependent on its R- or L-valueness.

He explicitly mentioned the **assignment operator** as an instance of an operation that has a sink argument.

He therefore gave this implementation as an example in the talk:

```
object_t& operator = (object_t x)
{ object_ = move(x.object_); return *this;  }
```

In later talks e.g. at the Going Native 2013, he repeated the guidelines but mentioned that a separate move assignment operator needs to be implemented due to a **language defect**:

This is a citation from his slides:

- Pass sink arguments per value and move or swap into place.
- A sink argument is any argument consumed of passed by the function.

  - The argument to assignment is a sink argument.
  - *However, due to a language defect, you must write a move assignment operator.*

I searched for information about this specific language defect but did not find any.

1. Can anybody explain what this language defect is and why an assignment operator using a sink argument is not working.
2. Will this language defect persist in C++14?

Thanks in advance,
Joachim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sean Parents answers this question in a comment of his in this [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning).

---

Lets say that you have a `class Foo` with an assignment operator as the example below:

```
class Foo {
  Foo& operator=(Foo o) noexcept {
    member = move(o.member);
    return *this; 
  }
};
```

And wrap a `Foo` object in a `struct`, say `struct wrap` like in the example below:

```
struct wrap { Foo m_ };
```

Then `wrap` will not get a default move assignment. For `wrap` to get a default `noexcept` move assignment, all members must have a `noexcept` move assignment - this determination is made by signature. That is the standard says that for `wrap` to get a default `noexcept` move assignment all members must have a move assignment with the signature `T& operator=(T&&) noexcept`.

The fix is to rephrase the requirement so it says that a struct or class will get a default `noexcept` move assignment if all members satisfies  `is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>` - which the above does. That is, we want to define the requirement in terms of the concept, or operation semantics, and not in terms of matching an exact signature.

---